# Is available to embed AdMob in my app that contains my youtube videos?

Tags: youtube-api

This is not programing question. I come in here from youtube API page by clicking 'Ask a Question'...;

I will make the app shows yoga videos using Youtube API. Those videos are mine. In that app, people can play my youtube videos. I will show AdMob on video list page. My plan is available?

Or, Except AdMob, I can insert AD onto video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not allowed to simply play YouTube content in an app. This is called framing.